# Calculate most frequent value in a array in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, solidity-0.5.x

I have an array something like [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2]. I want to find the most frequent value. If two are more are having highest frequency, the first occurance should be the result. I am passing it to function to get result. I don,t know where the error is but the result is not right. My function is not working as required.

````
function mode(uint[] memory array) public pure returns(uint)
    {
        uint  modeValue; 
        uint[] memory count; 
        uint  number; 
        uint maxIndex = 0;
        //uint zero=0;

    for (uint i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        number = array[i];
        count[number] = (count[number]) + 1;
        if (count[number] > maxIndex) {
            maxIndex = count[number];
        }
    }

    for (uint i =0;i<count.length; i++)
        if (count[i] == maxIndex) {
                modeValue=count[i];
                break;
            }

    return modeValue;
    }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your technical mistake is that `uint[] memory count` is not initialized, so any access attempt of the sort `count[number]` or `count[i]` will naturally cause your function to revert; you must find the maximum value in the input array, and then initialize `count = new uint[](maxInputValue + 1)`.

---

Your logical mistake is that instead of this:

```
if (count[number] > maxIndex) {
    maxIndex = count[number];
}
```

You should be doing this:

```
if (count[number] > count[maxIndex]) {
    maxIndex = number;
}
```

---

Your conceptual mistake (assuming that your input array is sorted as shown in the question) is that you don't need the `count` array to begin with, and you can simply keep the max count and its corresponding value as you go.

Comment: My array is not sorted always. So count is needed. I edited my function as uint[] memory count= new uint[](array.length); . Still the same error.

Comment: @Ramya: Using `array.length` here is wrong. In order to support `count[number]`, you should use "the maximum value in the array" + 1 instead. Can you see why?

Comment: In addition to that, your logic is completely wrong. Instead of `if (count[number] > maxIndex)` you should use `if (count[number] > count[maxIndex])`, and instead of `maxIndex = count[number]` you should use `maxIndex = number`. See updated answer.

Comment: I modified the code and removed the second for loop too. Works perfectly fine.Thanks for the timely support @goodvibration